# Can't get values from Array object to render React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I'm struggling with my student project where I need to render my shopping list with art categories. There are many items with different values.

```
const [shopList, setShopList] = useState(
    [{
        PORTRET: [{
            img: "img/portret_2.jpg",
            dimention: "40x80",
            price: "170",
            category: "PORTRET",
            id: 1
        },
        {
            img: "img/portret_1.jpg",
            dimention: "80x100",
            price: "190",
            category: "PORTRET",
            id: 2
        },
        {
            img: "img/portret_3.jpg",
            dimention: "80x120",
            price: "220",
            category: "PORTRET",
            id: 3
        }]
    },
    {
        SQUARE: [{
            img: "img/square_1.jpg",
            dimention: "40x80",
            price: "180",
            category: "SQUARE",
            id: 4
        },
        {
            img: "img/square_5.jpg",
            dimention: "40x80",
            price: "180",
            category: "SQUARE",
            id: 5
        },
        {
            img: "img/square_3.jpg",
            dimention: "40x80",
            price: "180",
            category: "SQUARE",
            id: 6
        },
        {
            img: "img/square_2.jpg",
            dimention: "40x80",
            price: "180",
            category: "SQUARE",
            id: 7
        },
        {
            img: "img/square_4.jpg",
            dimention: "40x80",
            price: "180",
            category: "SQUARE",
            id: 8
        }]
    },
    {
        LANDSCAPE: [{
            img: "img/landscape_1.jpg",
            dimention: "75x110",
            price: "220",
            category: "LANDSCAPE",
            id: 9
        }]
    },
    {
        CLOCK: [{
            img: "img/circle_1.jpg",
            dimention: "⌀32",
            price: "170",
            category: "CLOCK",
            id: 10
        },
        {
            img: "img/circle_2.jpg",
            dimention: "⌀32",
            price: "170",
            category: "CLOCK",
            id: 11
        }]
    },
    {
        OTHER: [{
            img: "img/other_1.jpg",
            dimention: "-",
            price: "250",
            category: "OTHER",
            id: 12
        },
        {
            img: "img/other_2.jpg",
            dimention: "-",
            price: "250",
            category: "OTHER",
            id: 13
        },
        {
            img: "img/horse.jpg",
            dimention: "-",
            price: "250",
            category: "OTHER",
            id: 14
        },
        {
            img: "img/tattoo.jpg",
            dimention: "-",
            price: "250",
            category: "OTHER",
            id: 15
        }]
    }
    ]
);
```

I made a react component where rendered items category and inside of it must give me a list of available arts.

```
const ShopList = ({ shopList }) => {
return (
    <div className="Section">
        {shopList.map((cat) => {
            return (Object.keys(cat).map((item) => {
                return (<div>
                    {console.log(item)}
                    <h3>{item.category}</h3>
                    <div className="bg-line"></div>
                    <div className="List-section" >
                        <div className="card" key={item.id}>
                            <div>
                                <img src={item.img} alt="" />
                                <div className="card-body">
                                    <h4 className="card-text">{item.dimention}cm</h4>
                                    <button type="button" name="button">{item.price}€</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>)
            }
            ))
        })
        }
    </div>
)
```

Couple days I've searching a solution of my problem. And using this line of code looks like the right way to make it works.

```
{shopList.map((cat) => {
            return (Object.keys(cat).map((item) => {
                return ( //render a values )}
```

I think my problem is inside of map function but I don't know  how to get nested objects and render there values.

**Adding a question**

Both solutions of mapping categories are work.

But I didn't get a right result what expected. It's looks like render each time when get a values from nested category and just push them in one column.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6CzQ.jpg)

**Solution**

Thanks to @buzatto and @Aron I've got a wanted result. Code down below is connected with React component.

```
const ShopList = ({ shopList }) => {
return (
    <div >
        {shopList.map(cat => {return Object.entries(cat).map(([category, items]) => {return (
                    <div className="Section">
                        <h3>{category}</h3>
                        <div className="bg-line" />
                        <div className="List-section">
                            {items.map(item => (
                                <div className="card" key={item.id}>
                                    <div>
                                        <img src={item.img} alt="" />
                                        <div className="card-body">
                                            <h4 className="card-text">{item.dimention}</h4>
                                            <button type="button" name="button">{item.price}€</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
            });
        })}
    </div>
);
```

};

Comment: You don't have a specific question here.  You might want to read this to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `Object.keys(cat)` will return, for example, for the first *cat* `['PORTRET']`. you want the values, not the key from that object. You should use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values). it will return an array with all values. You have only one key, value per object so you must access the index 0:

```
 return (Object.values(cat)[0].map((item) => {
```

Comment: Well it's works but I got a bug. It's render separately from each item not filter by category.

Comment: do you want items grouped together in some sort of card with its category as heading displaying once instead displaying for each item? maybe you could add your desired outcome to the question.

Comment: do you mean like this?  https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-nested-arrays-react?file=src/App.js

Comment: Yes, that's what I needed. Thank you very much. Now I just need to change my css to make it looks clean

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), which returns an array of `[key,value]` pairs.

```
const ShopList = ({ shopList }) => {
  return (
    <div className="Section">
      {shopList.map((cat) =>
        //  Using Object.entries to get an array of [categoryName, items] pairs
        // which we can then map over
        Object.entries(cat).map(([categoryName, items]) =>
          //  items is still an array so we need to map over it too
          items.map((item) => {
            return (
              <div>
                {/*  You can use categoryName here directly instead of item.category */}
                <h3>{categoryName}</h3>
                <div className="bg-line"></div>
                <div className="List-section">
                  <div className="card" key={item.id}>
                    <div>
                      <img src={item.img} alt="" />
                      <div className="card-body">
                        <h4 className="card-text">{item.dimention}cm</h4>
                        <button type="button" name="button">
                          {item.price}€
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          })
        )
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```